# Tensorflow 1.14 can't detect GPU with python 3.6 but see it in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to work with Mask R-CNN samples to practice detection and segmentation models. I am using python 3.6.8 with Tensorflow and Keras but program model starts training only with CPU and can't detect any GPU. At the same time Python 2.7 can see my GPU as it shown in code below.

I have installed NVidia driver 410, CUDA 10.0, cudnn 7.4.2, tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0 installed with pip and pip3.

To check is GPU available i used small python script:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

**Output for python:**

```
2019-09-16 12:17:21.621640: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-09-16 12:17:21.635692: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-09-16 12:17:21.720910: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-16 12:17:21.721429: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x558027aed070 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-09-16 12:17:21.721444: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1060 3GB, Compute Capability 6.1
2019-09-16 12:17:21.741624: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3408000000 Hz
2019-09-16 12:17:21.742628: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x558027ba37a0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-09-16 12:17:21.742663: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-09-16 12:17:21.742937: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-16 12:17:21.743542: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7845
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-09-16 12:17:21.743884: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-09-16 12:17:21.745776: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-09-16 12:17:21.747601: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-09-16 12:17:21.748031: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-09-16 12:17:21.750885: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-09-16 12:17:21.752588: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-09-16 12:17:21.757589: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]     Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-09-16 12:17:21.757765: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-16 12:17:21.758440: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-16 12:17:21.759102: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-09-16 12:17:21.759173: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-09-16 12:17:21.760528: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-09-16 12:17:21.760553: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2019-09-16 12:17:21.760564: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2019-09-16 12:17:21.760807: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-16 12:17:21.761483: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-16 12:17:21.762083: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 2287 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 13231116977719504797
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 2220022223072533235
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 579036656168733531
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 2398158848
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 14902085726432239020
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
]
```

**Output for python3:**

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0916 12:10:46.067314 140410557671232 __init__.py:308] Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
2019-09-16 12:10:46.084425: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-09-16 12:10:46.113540: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3408000000 Hz
2019-09-16 12:10:46.114038: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x495fd00 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-09-16 12:10:46.114054: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 5355211451834126024
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 8307771055363446310
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]
```

Where did I make mistake and how to fix this issue and detect GPU for Python3?

Comment: have your built CUDA and cuDNN from source? there are flags there which specify which python to be used. can you check your CUDA, cuDNN build instructions?

Comment: @B.Kocis Yes, I installed them from source. I did it like instructions said. Where can i check those instructions? Do you mean nvidia-smi and nvcc -V commands?

Comment: i think in the command for the build; there should be a flag to specify on top of which python to install. If there is non, check the default setting for the build. I remember I had once the same problem, but now I can't find a reference link for you.
Have you checked step 7 from this tutorial https://medium.com/@AlyShmahell/tutorial-how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-1-8-for-python-2-7-and-python-3-5-on-ubuntu-16-04-5f23537c75f0